# Auth0 - Update Root Attributes for Users - 403 Error: "You cannot update the following fields"

Tags: xamarin.forms, auth0

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms app with Auth0 and trying to let users update their own profile info using this [documentation for updating root attributes](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/guides/users/update-root-attributes-users) to no avail and keep getting the following error response that doesn't indicate which scope is missing.

> {"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"You cannot update the following fields: name","errorCode":"insufficient_scope"}

I am using the standard `Auth0.OidcClient` library similarly to [this example](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-mobile-apps-with-xamarin-forms-and-azure-functions/) to get the API access token properly while passing in all user update scopes I can find documented everywhere (`update:users` `update:current_user` `update:users_app_metadata` `update:current_user_metadata`  `update:current_user_identities`) as part of `Auth0ClientOptions`.  If `update:users` or `update:current_user_metadata` is not passed in as part of the requested scopes, the error message actually names it as an expected scope.  Hence, my perplexity at a now unnamed but still missing scope.

I have disabled sync on all social connections as required for root attributes to be editable.  As we are still in dev and it didn't work, I then disabled all social connections completely and just had the Auth0 database enabled to make sure the system just had Auth0 as the provider while logging in with a test user account that is from the Auth0 database.

When requesting the user patch, I have made sure to send the content type, cache-control, and the access token as authorization/bearer as [documented](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/guides/users/update-root-attributes-users).

The [documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/guides/users/update-root-attributes-users) sample is updating all root attributes, but the actual [API](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/patch_users_by_id) is supposedly able to update just one attribute at a time, so I am testing with just updating a single root attribute for now.  I get the same error when trying to update `name`, `email`, or `nickname`.

What am I missing?  Any advise or ideas?

UPDATE: I have narrowed down the issue to the user's consent grantInfo.  Login is logged as successful, but not all scopes passed in are actually accepted and consequently listed in the user grant.  Still no clue how to get the current user access to the `current_user` scopes via the `Auth0.OidcClient` library though.

```
     "grantInfo": {
      "id": "{ID-VALUE}",
      "audience": "https://{AUTHO-DOMAIN-NAME}/api/v2",
      "scope": "openid profile email",
      "expiration": null
    },
```

Comment: Can you look at the token you are getting back and see if it has the required scopes? jwt.io

Comment: I looked at the access token in jwt.io, and the only scopes returned are "openid profile email" even though "openid profile email sub update:current_user delete:current_user" were set as `Scope` in `Auth0.OidcClientOptions` on login.

Comment: It's not really documented anywhere as far as I can tell, but [this](https://community.auth0.com/t/management-api-client-grants-only-allow-current-user-to-update-themselves/26340/5) makes it sound like native apps are subject to the [same set of restricted scopes as single page apps](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/get-access-tokens-for-spas#available-scopes-and-endpoints), none of which are currently `update:current_user`.  

We are now investigating switching authentication to a a different system altogether.